# which firefox version is compatible with selenium 3.5.0?

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I tried with `Selenium 3.5.3 GeckoDriver 0.19 Firefox 55` but getting below exception:

```
Error: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: browser name not boolean
```

Code :

```
            DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
            WebDriver driver = null;
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "<path to gecko>\geckodriver.exe");
            cap.setBrowserName("firefox");
            URL sURL= null;
            cap.setCapability("firefox_binary", "<FIREFOX_PATH>"));  
            //Grid              
            sURL = new URL("http://localhost:5555/wd/hub"); 
            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(sURL, cap);
```

Also saw this thread https://seleniumhq.wordpress.com/2017/08/09/firefox-55-and-selenium-ide/ that selenium ide would not be supported anymore in `Firefox 55`. Whether selenium jar would be still supported?

Comment: Selenium 3.5.2 is compatible with above combination.

Comment: @Sudeepthi Same Exception with Selenium 3.5.2, firefox 55, gecko 0.19 :Same Exception Error: org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: browserName was not a boolean

Comment: @AnuChawla its better to give some code

Comment: @iamsankalp89 added Code

Comment: Let me check it. Unable to setup remotewebdriver

Answer (score 1):

It was a bad news for the tester community since [Selenium IDE no long works](https://seleniumhq.wordpress.com/2017/08/09/firefox-55-and-selenium-ide/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A%20Selenium%20%28The%20Official%20Selenium%20Blog%29) from Firefox 55 onwards. Now you have 2 choices:

1- Try with [previous version](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-older-version-of-firefox) of firefox (Temporary solution)

2- Use [Selenium IDE alternatives](https://www.katalon.com/resources-center/blog/selenium-ide-alternative-firefox-chrome/) (Highly Recommended)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use Firefox 54.0 and geckodriver v0.18.0.

Actually this links regarding Selenium IDE. You can use firefox 55 also.

Comment: Tried with Firefox 54.0 and gecko v0.18.0.. Same Exception Error: org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: browserName was not a boolean 
Build info: version: '3.5.2', revision: '10229a9020', time: '2017-08-21T17:54:21.164Z'

Comment: Can u paste it?